# Spivak's Calculus - Chapter 1 Question 23

Tags: calculus, analysis, epsilon-delta

In Spivak's Calculus Chapter 1 Question 23:

> Replace the question marks in the following statement ing $\varepsilon, x_0$ and $y_0$ so that the conclusion will be true:
>   If $y_0\neq 0$ and $$|y-y_0|<?  \qquad\text{and}\qquad  |x-x_0|<?$$ then $y\neq 0$ and $$ \bigg| \frac{x}{y}-\frac{x_0}{y_0}\bigg|<\varepsilon.$$

The answer in its Solution Manual is $$|x-x_0|<\min\bigg(\frac{\varepsilon}{2(1/|y_0|+1)},1 \bigg)$$ and $$|y-y_0|<\min\bigg( \frac{|y_0|}{2},\frac{\varepsilon|y_0|^2}{4(|x_0|+1)} \bigg).$$ The latter is same as my solution, but the first is a bit different. So I wonder if $$|x-x_0|<\min\bigg(\frac{\varepsilon |y_0|}{4},1 \bigg)$$, is the solution still be true?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|x-x_0|<\min\bigg(\frac{\varepsilon |y_0|}{4},1 \bigg)$ is wrong, here's why:

We have:

\begin{align*}
\bigg| \frac{x}{y}-\frac{x_0}{y_0}\bigg| &\leq \frac{\left | x \right |\left | y_{0}-y \right |+\left | y \right |\left | x_{0}-x \right |}{\left | yy_{0} \right |}\\
&\leq \frac{\left | x-x_{0} \right |\left | y-y_{0} \right |}{\left | yy_{0} \right |}+\frac{\left | x_{0} \right |\left | y_{0}-y \right |}{\left | yy_{0} \right |}+\frac{\left | y \right |\left | x_{0}-x \right |}{\left | yy_{0} \right |}
\end{align*}

where I used: $\left | x \right |\leq \left | x-x_{0} \right |+\left | x_{0} \right |$

Now if you consider the first term, i.e. $\frac{\left | x-x_{0} \right |\left | y-y_{0} \right |}{\left | yy_{0} \right |}$ alone and try to get it to be smaller than $\frac{\varepsilon }{2}$ you would end up with:

$\frac{\left | x-x_{0} \right |\left | y-y_{0} \right |}{\left | yy_{0} \right |}\leq \frac{\left | x-x_{0} \right |\frac{y_{0}}{2}}{\frac{\left | y_{0} \right |^{2}}{2}}= \frac{2\left | x-x_{0} \right |}{\left | y_{0} \right |}< \frac{\varepsilon }{2}$ giving the result you found which is $|x-x_0|<\frac{\varepsilon |y_0|}{4}$.

But looking at the decomposition above you realise this is wrong because you need to consider:

$\frac{\left | x-x_{0} \right |}{\left | yy_{0} \right |}(\left | y-y_{0} \right |+\left | y \right |)$ instead of $\frac{\left | x-x_{0} \right |\left | y-y_{0} \right |}{\left | yy_{0} \right |}$

The correct answer for the first is the one stated by the manual as:
$\left | \frac{x}{y}-\frac{x_{0}}{y_{0}} \right |=\left | \frac{x}{y}-\frac{x}{y_{0}}+\frac{x}{y_{0}}-\frac{x_{0}}{y_{0}} \right |\leq \left | x \right |\left | \frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_{0}} \right |+\left |\frac{1}{y_{0}}  \right |\left | x-x_{0} \right |$

So:
$\left |\frac{1}{y_{0}}  \right |\left | x-x_{0} \right |\leq \frac{\frac{1}{\left |y_{0}  \right |}\varepsilon }{2(\frac{1}{\left |y_{0}  \right |}+1)}\leq \frac{\varepsilon }{2}$

Comment: Different "decompositions" end up with different solutions. I mean your solution is also true its own right.

Comment: @H.Ergul But do you agree that if you derived your answer the way I presumed you did, then it's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

To solve question 23 you use the inequalities from questions 21 and 22, which I give here with their proofs.

**Qu. 21)** If 
$$|x-x_0|<\min\bigg(\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}, 1 \bigg)\quad\text{and}\quad |y-y_0|< \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)} \tag{1}$$
then $|xy-x_0y_0|<\varepsilon$.

***Proof:***

Since $|x-x_0|<1$ we have $|x|-|x_0|<|x-x_0|<1\Longrightarrow |x|<|x_0|+1$, and so
\begin{align*}
|xy-x_0y_0|&=|x(y-y_0)-y_0(x_0-x)|\\
&\le|x||y-y_0|+|y_0||x_0-x|\\
&< (1+ |x_0|)\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}+|y_0|\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}\\
&<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.
\end{align*}

**Qu. 22)** If $y_0\neq0$ and
$$|y-y_0|<\min\bigg(\frac{|y_0|}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon |y_0|^2}{2} \bigg), \tag{2}$$
then $y\neq0$ and
$$\bigg| \frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\bigg|<\varepsilon.$$

***Proof:***

$|y_0|-|y|\le|y-y_0|<\frac{|y_0|}{2}\Longrightarrow |y|>\frac{|y_0|}{2}$. Since $y\neq0$ we have
$$\frac{1}{|y|}<\frac{2}{|y_0|}.$$
Then
$$\bigg| \frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\bigg|=\frac{|y-y_0|}{|y||y_0|}<\frac{1}{|y|}\cdot\frac{2}{|y_0|}\cdot\frac{\varepsilon |y_0|^2}{2}=\varepsilon.$$

**Qu. 23)** If $y_0\neq 0$ and
 $$|y-y_0|<\min\bigg( \frac{|y_0|}{2},\frac{\varepsilon|y_0|^2}{4(|x_0|+1)} \bigg)  \qquad\text{and}\qquad  |x-x_0|<\min\bigg(\frac{\varepsilon}{2(1/|y_0|+1)},1 \bigg)$$ 
 then $y\neq 0$ and 
$$ \bigg| \frac{x}{y}-\frac{x_0}{y_0}\bigg|<\varepsilon.$$

***Proof:***
We note that 
$$\bigg| \frac{x}{y}-\frac{x_0}{y_0}\bigg|=\bigg| x\cdot\frac{1}{y}-x_0\cdot\frac{1}{y_0}\bigg|$$
which is just $|xy-x_0y_0|$ of question 21 but with $y$, and $y_0$ replaced by $\frac{1}{y}$, and $\frac{1}{y_0}$ respectively, where $y\neq0$. Hence we require, by inequality (1) that
$$|x-x_0|<\min\bigg(\frac{\varepsilon}{2(1/|y_0|+1)}, 1 \bigg)\quad\text{and}\quad \bigg|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\bigg| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}. \tag{3}$$

Now in question 22, inequality (2) allows $\big| \frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\big|<\varepsilon$. However we must replace the $\varepsilon$ of inequality (2) with $\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}$ of (3) to give:

$$|y-y_0| <\min\bigg(\frac{|y_0|}{2}, \frac{\varepsilon |y_0|^2}{4(|x_0|+1)} \bigg).$$

---

To see why 
$$|x-x_0|<\min\bigg(\frac{\varepsilon |y_0|}{4},1 \bigg)$$
is the wrong choice, we rework question 22: 
\begin{align*}
\bigg| \frac{x}{y}-\frac{x_0}{y_0}\bigg|&= \frac{\left|xy_0-x_0y\right|}{\left|yy_0\right|}\\
&=\frac{ |x (y_0-y)- y(x_0-x)|}{|y||y_0|}\\
&\leq\frac{ | x ||y-y_0|}{|y||y_0|}+\frac{|x-x_0|}{|y_0|}\\
&\leq\frac{ (1+| x _0|)|y-y_0|}{|y||y_0|}+\frac{|x-x_0|}{|y_0|}\\
&<\frac{ (1+| x _0|)}{|y||y_0|}\cdot\frac{\varepsilon |y_0|^2}{4(|x_0|+1)}+\frac{|x-x_0|}{|y_0|}\tag{$\star$}\\
&<\frac{2}{|y_0|}\cdot\frac{ 1}{|y_0|}\cdot\frac{\varepsilon |y_0|^2}{4}+\frac{|x-x_0|}{|y_0|}\\
&=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{|x-x_0|}{|y_0|}.
\end{align*}
Where we have used
$$\frac{1}{|y|}<\frac{2}{|y_0|}$$
from question 22 in the penultimate inequality. Now if $|x-x_0|<\min\big(\frac{\varepsilon |y_0|}{4},1 \big)$, we should have
$$\bigg| \frac{x}{y}-\frac{x_0}{y_0}\bigg|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}=\frac{3\varepsilon}{4}.$$
Now here could be a source of confusion because for sure $\frac{3\varepsilon}{4}<\varepsilon$, but that is not what is required. What is required is for  $\big| \frac{x}{y}-\frac{x_0}{y_0}\big|<\varepsilon$, and as such we need to end up with two numbers $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$, say, which add up to $\varepsilon$, which is some fixed number $>0$. The point is that when you assert something is *less than* $\varepsilon$ in the proof, you don't know if it is *less than* $\frac{3\varepsilon}{4}$, indeed, it could be greater than $\frac{3\varepsilon}{4}$, just as long as it is $<\varepsilon$.

The answer given in (3) works since
$$\frac{|x-x_{0}|}{|y_0|} <\frac{\varepsilon/|y_0|}{2(1/|y_0|+1)}< \frac{\varepsilon }{2},$$
which yields the desired $\varepsilon$ when plugged into $(\star)$.

Comment: You made my day! Thank you for the excellent explanation and the effort put into this post.

Comment: @FuzzyPixelz No problem, glad you liked it. Cheers :)